# Component getting redux state asynchronously?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have a problem with redux state. Pagination component has the method

```
const setPage = page => {
    props.removeFilterParam('page');
    props.addFilterParam('page', page);
    props.getProducts();
}
```

`props.removeFilterParam` and  `props.addFilterParam` are redux actions that modify redux store, `getProducts` is method on parent component that looks like this

```
async getProducts() {
    try {
        console.log('Filter before', this.props.filter);
        setTimeout(() => console.log('After', this.props.filter), 2000)
        // const slug = this.props.match.params.slug;
        // const queryString = transformToQueryString(this.props.filter);
        // await this.props.getProductsRequest(`/api/categories/${slug}/${queryString}`);
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
    }
}
```

Parent component is connected with redux store. When `getProducts` is called in console I see this:

[image]

So after modifying the redux state by `addFilterParam`, the changes is not applied in `getProducts` function synchronously.

Actions are:

```
export const addFilterParam = (name, value) => ({
    type: ADD_FILTER_PARAM,
    name,
    value
})

export const removeFilterParam = (name, value) => ({
    type: REMOVE_FILTER_PARAM,
    name,
    value
});
```

Reducer is:

```
const filterReducer = (state = {}, action) => {
    switch(action.type) {
        case ADD_FILTER_PARAM:
            if (state.hasOwnProperty(action.name)) {
                if (Array.isArray(action.value)) {
                    state[action.name] = [...state[action.name], ...action.value];
                } else {
                    if (state[action.name].indexOf(action.value) === -1) {
                        state[action.name].push(action.value);
                    }
                }
            } else {
                if (Array.isArray(action.value)) {
                    state[action.name] = action.value;
                } else {
                    state[action.name] = [action.value];
                }
            }
            return {...state};

        case REMOVE_FILTER_PARAM:
            if (state.hasOwnProperty(action.name)) {
                if (action.value) {
                    let args = state[action.name];
                    const index = args.indexOf(action.value);

                    if (index !== -1) {
                        args.splice(index, 1);

                        if (args.length) {
                            state[action.name] = args;
                        } else {
                            delete state[action.name];
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    delete state[action.name];
                }
            }

            return {...state};

        case CLEAR_FILTER:
            return {};

        default: return state; 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Redux actions are not synchronous. They don't change your component props on-the-fly. What they do is trigger an action that *can* change a reducer (and just like react `setState`, [it's not synchronous](https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-state.html#why-is-setstate-giving-me-the-wrong-value)). They will sure be changed on next `render()` call. If you need to be notified when a prop is changed, you can use [`componentDidUpdate()`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidupdate) callback. In your example:

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
  const { filter } = this.props
  if (filter !== prevProps.filter) {
    // filter changed
    console.log('Filter changed', filter)
  }
}
```